# I can't use orderBy query from firestore if where is used Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am retreiving a list from Firestore and I need to use query where to retrieve specific UserID but at the same time I need also to order this list by the timestamp.
Using orderBy and where is not possible to get this is my code:

```
Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.275,
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('ConfirmedCart').orderBy('cartDate',descending: false)
              .where('idConsultant', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshotConfirmedCart) {
            if (!snapshotConfirmedCart.hasData)
              return Container(
                  width: 40,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ));
```

as you can see above orderBy is used and can't fetch data, If I removed orderBy, I get the data but without my specific order.

Comment: did u create an index?

Comment: U mean on Firebase side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('ConfirmedCart')
              .where('idConsultant', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.uid)
              .orderBy('cartDate',descending: false)
```

When performing compound queries you must create a [composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) in the firebase console. When the above query is executed you will get a link in the log that will take you to the console to create the index.

Comment: Ok thanks I am doing right now seems it takes long time to perform it...